# How to write an algorithm to arrange objects in respective slots

Tags: php

How can we write an algorithm in PHP to move the objects to their correct positions with the following constraints in place

```
slot-1  slot-2  slot-3  slot-4  slot-5
obj-4   obj-5   Empty   obj-3   obj-1
```

- Two objects cannot swap places. For example, you cannot swap obj-4 and
  obj-1 in the above example.
- You can however move a object into an empty slot.
- So, in the above example if you bring obj-1 into it's
  correct position by first moving obj-4 into slot-3(which is empty)
  and then move obj-1 to slot-1 (which is now empty because obj-4 was
  moved to slot-3)

Any idea would be helpfull, so that i can try myself.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @Reeno - no im not getting any idea from where to start, i was confused. any idea? so that i can try.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad and there is not code to fix.

Answer (score 0):

simply put:

1. Step: check which slot is empty.
2. Step: take the object which belongs in the slot and transfer it
3. If the slot has no fitting obj-n transfer the next object into the slot which is not in its correct slot (example: if slot-2 is empty there is no fitting object. So we just transfer the next obj which is not in its specified slot.)
4. Start again until Step 3 does not find an item anymore which is not in its specified slot.

CODE Edit:

```
variable boolean1 = False

Execute for-loop so many times until boolean1 is True

for x in arrayslots: (1st for-loop)

    if x is empty: 
       get x.slot_number # Step 1
       for y in objects:
           if slot_number==y_object_number:
               transfer object # Step 2 
               break 1st for-loop #(and start anew -> Step 3)
       if x == empty # no obj. could be found for the slot
           for x in objects:
               if x is NOT in the right slot:
                   transfer x to empty slot
                   break the 1st for--loop #(and start anew -> Step 3)
            boolean1 = True #You only reach this when the loop finds that no objects are in the wrong place anymore.
```

Comment: havent programmed in php for a long time but something like this (see edit above in a min)

Comment: does this help? You still have to transfer it into compilable code in php but I think it is a good start - I shouldnt have to do all the work for you ;)